# Spring boot JMS using different messages class

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using spring boot.
I want to use different models at both sender and receiver so that they don't depend to the same model (receiver doesn't need to add model of sender to classpath).
**1) Should I do that?**
**2) And how can I do that?**

**Sender:**

```
AccountEvent accountEvent = new com.dspc.account.domain.dto.AccountEvent(createdAccount.getId(), EventType.CREATED);
jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(new ActiveMQTopic("VirtualTopic.ACCOUNT-EVENT-TOPIC"), accountEvent);
```

**Receiver:**

```
@JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.AgentGenerator.VirtualTopic.ACCOUNT-EVENT-TOPIC")
public void receive(com.dspc.devicemgmt.domain.dto.AccountEvent accountEvent) {
    System.out.println(accountEvent);
}
```

**JMS config of both sender and receiver:**

```
@Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
}
```

**Get exception when receiving message:**

```
[com.dspc.account.domain.dto.AccountEvent]; nested exception is 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.dspc.account.domain.dto.AccountEvent
```

**Note that there are 2 different packages:**

- com.dspc.account.domain.dto.AccountEvent
- com.dspc.devicemgmt.domain.dto.AccountEvent

**I'm thinking about creating a common message model. How do you think?**

```
public class DspcCommonMessage {
    private Map<String, String> properties;
    private Optional<byte[]> payLoad = Optional.empty();

    public Map<String, String> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Map<String, String> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public Optional<byte[]> getPayLoad() {
        return payLoad;
    }

    public void setPayLoad(Optional<byte[]> payLoad) {
        this.payLoad = payLoad;
    }
}
```

**Sender and receiver:**

```
    public void publishMessage(com.dspc.account.domain.dto.AccountEvent accountEvent) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String messageAsString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(accountEvent);
        DspcCommonMessage dspcMessage = new DspcCommonMessage();
        dspcMessage.setPayLoad(Optional.of(messageAsString.getBytes()));
        jmsMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(new ActiveMQTopic("VirtualTopic.ACCOUNT-EVENT-TOPIC"), dspcMessage);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "Consumer.AgentGenerator.VirtualTopic.ACCOUNT-EVENT-TOPIC")
    public void receive(com.dspc.common.domain.DspcCommonMessage dspcCommonMessage) {
        String jsonBody = new String(dspcCommonMessage.getPayload());
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        com.dspc.devicemgmt.domain.dto.AccountEvent accountEvent = objectMapper.readValue(jsonBody,
                com.dspc.devicemgmt.domain.dto.AccountEvent accountEvent.class);

        System.out.println(accountEvent);
    }
```